# GWT simple DockPanel usage error

Tags: java, gwt, uibinder, dockpanel

why this "code" fails

```
<g:DockPanel unit="px">
    <g:south size="100">
        <g:TextBox ui:field="host" text="localhost"/>
    </g:south>
    <g:south size="100">
        <g:TextBox ui:field="port" text="3287"/>
    </g:south>
</g:DockPanel>
```

while this

```
<g:HorizontalPanel>
    <g:cell>
        <g:TextBox ui:field="host" text="localhost"/>
    </g:cell>
    <g:cell>
        <g:TextBox ui:field="port" text="3287"/>
    </g:cell>
</g:HorizontalPanel>
```

doesn't?

Additional info:

stacktrace

```
ERROR: Deferred binding failed for 'client.view.EnterPage.EnterPageUiBinder'; expect subsequent failures. 
ERROR: Unable to load module entry point class client.Dbweb (see associated exception for details). java.lang.RuntimeException: Deferred binding failed for 'client.view.EnterPage$EnterPageUiBinder' (did you forget to inherit a required module?)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.GWTBridgeImpl.create(GWTBridgeImpl.java:53)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT.create(GWT.java:98)
    at client.view.EnterPage.<clinit>(EnterPage.java:27)
    at client.Dbweb.onModuleLoad(Dbweb.java:15)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.onLoad(ModuleSpace.java:396)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.loadModule(OophmSessionHandler.java:183)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:510)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:352)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: com.google.gwt.core.ext.UnableToCompleteException: (see previous log entries)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.rebind(ModuleSpace.java:595)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.rebindAndCreate(ModuleSpace.java:455)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.GWTBridgeImpl.create(GWTBridgeImpl.java:49)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT.create(GWT.java:98)
    at client.view.EnterPage.<clinit>(EnterPage.java:27)
    at client.Dbweb.onModuleLoad(Dbweb.java:15)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.onLoad(ModuleSpace.java:396)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.loadModule(OophmSessionHandler.java:183)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:510)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:352)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

binder creation

```
interface EnterPageUiBinder extends UiBinder<HTMLPanel, EnterPage> {
}

private static EnterPageUiBinder ourUiBinder = GWT.create(EnterPageUiBinder.class);
```

both panels description I wrap into

```
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder'
         xmlns:g='urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui'>
    <g:HTMLPanel>
    panel description
    bla-bla
    </g:HTMLPanel>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

**upd** If you have same problem you can go after @Peter Knego's solution or do smt like

```
<g:DockLayoutPanel unit="PX">
      <g:south size="100">
          <g:TextBox ui:field="host" text="localhost"/>
      </g:south>
      <g:south size="100">
          <g:TextBox ui:field="port" text="3287"/>
      </g:south>
  </g:DockLayoutPanel>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When in doubt consult [the source](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#A1edwVHBClQ/user/src/com/google/gwt/uibinder/elementparsers/DockPanelParser.java).

The correct layout is:

```
    <g:DockPanel>
        <g:Dock direction="SOUTH" size="100px">
            <g:TextBox text="localhost"/>
        </g:Dock>
        <g:Dock direction="SOUTH" size="100px">
            <g:TextBox text="3287"/>
        </g:Dock>
    </g:DockPanel>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure you're supposed to have two time a south panel in your DockPanel. And I think your supposed to use DockLayoutPanel now.

Comment: It failed even with single element and unfortunately there is same exception with `DockLayoutPanel`.

Comment: I'll let someone else give you an answer also, I haven't installed GWT on my notebook and I'm not familiar enough the help you without trying.